# Задача "Угадай число"

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

> Август и Беатриса играют в игру. Август загадал натуральное число от 1 до n. Беатриса пытается угадать это число, для этого она называет некоторые множества натуральных чисел. Август отвечает Беатрисе YES, если среди названных ей чисел есть задуманное или NO в противном случае. После нескольких заданных вопросов Беатриса запуталась в том, какие вопросы она задавала и какие ответы получила и просит вас помочь ей определить, какие числа мог задумать Август.
>
> Формат ввода
>
> Первая строка входных данных содержит число n — наибольшее число, которое мог загадать Август. Далее идут строки, содержащие вопросы Беатрисы. Каждая строка представляет собой набор чисел, разделенных пробелами. После каждой строки с вопросом идет ответ Августа: YES или NO. Наконец, последняя строка входных данных содержит одно слово HELP.
>
> Формат вывода
>
> Вы должны вывести (через пробел, в порядке возрастания) все числа, которые мог задумать Август.

Моя реализация:

```
n = int(input())
ans = set(range(1, n + 1))
q = 0
while True:
    q = input()
    if q == "HELP":
        break
    else:
        a = set(list(map(int, q.split())))
        q = input()
        if q == "YES":
            ans = ans & a
        else:
            ans = ans - a
ans = sorted(ans)
print(*ans)
```

По мнению проверяющей системы можно оптимизировать код и ускориться. Каким образом?

Answer (score 2):

Изменила `ans = ans & a` на  `ans &= a`, и `ans = ans - a` на `ans -= a` — проверяющая система довольна. Получается, такие на первый взгляд незначительные изменения действительно влияют на скорость?

Comment: Выражение, использующее оператор присваивания `-=`, такое как
`x -= y`  
эквивалентно
`x = x - y`  
за исключением того, что x вычисляется только один раз. Тоже справедливо для оператора `&=`.

Answer (score 0):

Я так реализовал:

```
n = int(input())
a = set(range(1, n + 1))


for i in range(n):
    try:
        z = set([int(i) for i in input().split()])
        b = input()
    except ValueError:
        break
    
    if b == 'YES':
        a &= z
    else:
        a -= z
        
print(*sorted(a))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]