# Угадай число, программа учитывает не все варианты

Tags: python, множества

проблема в коде по следующей задаче:

```
Август и Беатриса играют в игру. Август загадал натуральное число от 1 до n. 
Беатриса пытается угадать это число, для этого она называет
некоторые множества натуральных чисел. Август отвечает Беатрисе YES, если среди
названных ей чисел есть задуманное или NO в противном случае. 
После нескольких заданных вопросов Беатриса запуталась в том, какие вопросы она задавала и какие
ответы получила и просит вас помочь ей определить, какие числа мог задумать Август.

Входные данные
Первая строка входных данных содержит число n — наибольшее число, которое мог загадать Август. 
Далее идут строки, содержащие вопросы Беатрисы. Каждая строка представляет собой набор чисел, разделённых
пробелами. После каждой строки с вопросом идет ответ Августа: YES или NO.

Наконец, последняя строка входных данных содержит одно слово HELP.

Выходные данные
Вы должны вывести (через пробел, в порядке возрастания) все числа, которые мог задумать Август.

Примеры
входные данные
10
1 2 3 4 5
YES
2 4 6 8 10
NO
HELP
выходные данные
1 3 5
```

Написала по ней код:

```
n=int(input()) 
mn=[] 
a=[]
for i in range(1, n+1):
    mn.append(i) 
mn=set(mn)
x=set()
q="" 
while q!="HELP":
    q=input() 
    if q=="HELP":
        break 
    else:
        a.append(q)
for i in range(0, len(a)-1, 2):
    if a[i+1]=="YES":
        q=[] 
        w=a[i]
        for j in range(len(w)):
            if w[j]!=" ":
                q.append(int(w[j]))
        #


        cu=list(mn) 
        for k in range(len(cu)):
            if cu[k] not in q:
                mn.discard(cu[k])
    else:
        q=[] 
        w=a[i]
        for j in range(len(w)):
            if w[j]!=" ":
                q.append(int(w[j]))
        #

        for k in range(len(q)):
            if q[k] in mn:
                mn.discard(q[k])
               

print(*sorted(mn))
```

Но в приведённом в задаче тесте программа вместо 1 3 5 выводит 3 5, к тому же на 2 последних тестах проверяющей системы(не известны) работает лишком долго. Помогите пожалуйста!!!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/869316

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем коде есть две пробемы:

1. Этот код обрабатывает только числа из единственных цифр. Если Беатриса загадает *10*, вы учтёте единицу и ноль по отдельности. По этой причине в вашем решении не хватает единицы в ответе:

```
        for j in range(len(w)):
            if w[j]!=" ":
                q.append(int(w[j]))
```

2. В начале программы вы пытаетесь составить множество всех чисел. Строить его долго, оно может не поместиться в память. Я не знаю реальна ли эта проблема, зависит от ограничений на *n*.

Если предположить что *n* не велико, можно обойтись прямолинейным решением. Формируем множество всех кандидатов `candidates`, если ответ положительный, то ограничиваем его множеством подходящих чисел (`candidates &= s`), если отрицательный - удаляем неподходящие числа (`candidates -= s`):

```
n = int(input())
candidates = set(range(1, n + 1))

while True:
    line = input()
    if line == 'HELP':
        break
    s = set(map(int, line.split()))
    reply = input()
    if reply == 'YES':
        candidates &= s
    else:
        candidates -= s

for i in sorted(candidates):
    print(i)
```

Если *n* может быть очень велико, создать первоначальное множество не получится. Тогда действуем так: до первого положительного ответа накапливаем множество отвергнутых чисел. После первого положительного ответа, действуем как в предыдущем варианте:

```
n = int(input())

yes = None
no = set()
while True:
    line = input()
    if line == 'HELP':
        break

    s = set(map(int, line.split()))
    reply = input()
    if reply == 'YES':
        if yes is None:
            yes = s
        else:
            yes &= s
    else:
        no |= s

    if yes is not None:
        yes -= no
        no = set()

if yes is None:
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if i not in no:
            print(i)
else:
    for i in sorted(yes):
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать операции разности и пересечения множеств:

```py
n = int(input())

all_numbers = set(range(1, n + 1))

inp = input()

while inp != 'HELP':
    nums = set(map(int, inp.split()))
    if input() == 'YES':
        all_numbers = all_numbers & nums
    else:
        all_numbers = all_numbers - nums
    inp = input()

print(' '.join(map(str, all_numbers)))
```

Comment: @CrazyElf Не очень понял. Т.к. загадывается одно число и оно есть и в "1 3" и в "3 5" то это может быть только число 3 т.к. 1 и 5 входят только в одно множество (Если загадано число 1 то в "1 3" должно быть `YES` а "3 5" должно быть `NO`). Если мы будем использовать `|`, то возможными будут и 1 и 3 и 5

Comment: `all_numbers` - плохая идея.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy В связи с названием или чем-то ещё?

Comment: Он занимает очень много памяти в некоторых случаях. Например: *n = 10^20*, *1 -> YES*. Сама задача решается в одну операцию. Но `all_numbers` никуда не влезет.

Comment: А, всё, я недопонял задачу. Удаляю свой комментарий )  Ну, тогда осталось только `all_numbers` убрать. Просто пересекайте все `YES` между собой, но в самый первый раз, когда ещё ничего нет - просто инициализируйте множество этим первым `YES` списком.

Comment: `all_numbers = all_numbers & nums` -> `all_numbers &= nums`. Вторая запись иногда намного быстрее.